# NGINX 1.6.2 reverse proxy for multiple web servers with different context

Tags: tomcat, ssl, nginx, webserver, reverse-proxy

I have 2 seperate java web (apple & banana) applications running in 2 seperate Tomcat servlet containers on the same physical Linux server:

- http://localhost:8080
- http://localhost:8085

I'd like to use NGINX to act as a reverse proxy and forward the SSL encrypted HTTP traffic to its respective Tomcat instance for servicing.

I've researched this on the web in several places, there are instances of how to load balance, cache, but can't manage to find anything relevant to my scenario, or what is wrong with my configuration. Here is my /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/default configuration:

```
upstream apple {
    server  21.21.21.21:8080;
}
upstream banana {
    server  21.21.21.21:8085;
}
server {
    listen 80;
    return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
}

server {
    listen 443;
    ssl_certificate     /etc/nginx/server.crt;
    ssl_certificate_key     /etc/nginx/server.key;
    ssl on;
    ssl_session_cache   builtin:1000    shared:SSL:10m;
    ssl_protocols   TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2;
    ssl_ciphers HIGH:!aNULL:!eNULL:!EXPORT:!CAMELLIA:!DES:!MD5:!PSK:!RC4;
    ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;
    access_log  /var/log/nginx/contint.hln.access.log;
    proxy_set_header    HOST $host;
    proxy_set_header    X-Real-IP   $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header    X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_set_header    X-Forwarded-Proto   $scheme;
    proxy_read_timeout 90;

    location /banana/ {
        proxy_pass  http://banana;
        }

    location /apple/ {
        proxy_pass  http://apple;
        }

#    location ~* \.(css|js|gif|jpe?g|png)$ { # -- This doesn't help with caching, rather seems to filter them from the page
#        expires 20m;
#        }
}
```

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: So what *is* wrong with your configuration?